# How to change background color in perticular blogger post not for all posts?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change background color of perticular blogger post but when I applied many tricks, many errors came in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Blogger conditional tag for the post url and give the css styles you wish:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;URL_OF_YOUR_BLOG_POST&quot;'>

/* PLACE YOUR CSS CODE HERE - EXAMPLE FOR BODY BACKGROUND COLOR YELLOW: */
 body {
   background: #ff0;
 }

</b:if>
```

More info: https://ultimatebloggerguide.blogspot.com/2016/07/blogger-conditional-tags-for-page-types.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference the One Post by id to apply the CSS rule only to the particular post.

You may also reference the post by its position and class name.

Comment: This is a very vague and broad answer to a vague, broad and unclear questions. Questions that are missing clarity, detail or debugging details should not be answered until the Op clarifies to allow an accurate answer. Use the comment option instead (you unlock it at 50 reputation).